# How to generate namespaced XML attribute dynamically in XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xml-namespaces

How is it possible to generate namespaced XML attributes dynamically in XSLT? For example, we can have the following XML document using different attributes, such as `attr1:foo` or `attr2:bar`:

```
<a xmlns="http://example.com/"
   xmlns:attr1="http://example.com/attr1#"
   xmlns:attr2="http://example.com/attr2#">
  <b attr1:foo=""/>
  <b attr2:bar=""/>
</a>
```

Suppose we want to transform the document and change the values of all attributes to `...`. How should we construct these attributes? A natural option how to go about this would be to use [`<xsl:attribute>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#creating-attributes). But what QName should we use as its `name` attribute? The function [`name()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-name) can return the QName of the attribute as a string. Naïve XSL template might look like this:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">...</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

However, since `name()` returns the QName as string, this solution requires to have predefined the namespace prefix bindings via `xmlns` in the XSLT (e.g., `xmlns:attr1="http://example.com/attr1#"`).

Then I was wondering if using the `namespace` attribute of `<xsl:attribute>` is the way to go:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
  <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}"
                 namespace="{namespace-uri()}">...</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

This solution seems to work, but I think it's hardly best practice in XSLT. Do you know a better solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what do you know about the source document's structure:

- If you know the namespaces used and their prefix bindings, then
  declare them in your stylesheet and use what you called a "naïve XSL
  template".
- Otherwise copy the namespace (URI), as shown in your second template.

---

Note also that you can combine the two as follows:

```
<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">...</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

With some processors (e.g. Saxon 6.5) this will ensure that the original prefixes are re-used in the result; other processors (e.g. libxslt and Xalan) will do that anyway.

Comment: I don't know the namespace prefix bindings in advance. This is why I want to create the namespaced attributes dynamically.

Comment: Then I don't know of a better solution than your second template. Why do you think it's not best practice?

Comment: OK, I just wasn't sure if it's idiomatic XSLT. I thought there's a simpler way how to do it.